# What should the primary and secondary IP address be when setting up STUN server for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ip, stun

I'm attempting to set up a STUN server using STUN server for Node.js:

https://github.com/enobufs/stun

The readme has the following guidance:

> Place a config file named as node-stun.ini in
> your current directory. The config file should look like following.
> (These local loopback addresses should be routable public IP addresses
> in the real settings, of course)
>
> [primary] host = 127.0.0.1
>
> [secondary] host = 127.0.0.2

Does anyone know what the primary and secondary IPs should be? Should the primary be the IP address of my STUN server machine? What should the secondary be?

Could I set them as localhost and route requests to the server with nginx?

Finally, why does the software need to refer to these IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, STUN requires two unique public IP addresses on the server. But most client implementations only need one and don't use the alternate/secondary address.  And the server code needs to know what these addresses are for two reasons:

1. So that the server knows which address to bind the sockets to. (It would need the local ip addresses for each)
2. So that the server can advertise the alternate IP address when a binding request hits the primary IP.  (It needs to know the public IP addresses of the host if its behind a NAT with port forwarding).

If you don't have a secondary IP address to offer, then give in any address that allows the server to run.  This will break STUN behavior and filtering tests, but rarely do clients need this.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why there needs to be sockets (point 1) involved. Isn't the job of a STUN server to just ping back a client's external IP address?

Comment: The STUN server has two jobs.  First is to just reply back with the clients external IP address **and port**.  The second is to offer a way for the client to infer what type of NAT it is behind.  That's why a second IP address is needed.  Since most P2P/VOIP clients just follow the ICE methodology, NAT behavior/filtering type detection isn't so useful.   More details here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5780